# How is sign up page constructed?

Tags: meanjs

I know this is a very basic question but was wondering whether someone can give me a pointer to where exactly the build of the sign up page is constructed.  I can find the social media sign up code and the \modules\users\client\views\authentication\signup.client.view.html but what I can't work out is what is telling the displayed page to present the social sign up section followed by the view html etc.  Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,

Sean

Edit: I built the app by cloning version 0.5 from github.  Run gulp to load server.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us how you did the build first.

Comment: Cloned version 0.5 from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing is handled by Angular via the ui-router module.

If you check the file `/modules/users/client/config/users.client.routes.js`, you will see a section where there are many ui-router states defined as well as their url and their templateUrl.

The ui-router module allows you to have states and nested states (i.e. `authentication` state and `authentication.signup` which is a child state of `authentication`).